# Running chrome with remote-shell-port makes console.log stop working

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

If I save the following line to an html file and open the file in chrome, it works fine.

```
<script> console.log('hello') </script>
```

But if you run chrome with `--remote-shell-port=9222` the log doesn't appear in the console.

Anybody know of a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remote-shell-port flag exposes V8 debugging protocol which basically
supports only JavaScript debugging capabilities available in V8 JavaScript
engine used in Chrome. Console is a feature of the browser and V8 knows
nothing about it like many other features including DOM and Network inspection.
This one of the reasons we're working on a new remote debugging protocol
which will cover other domains as well. It is in development phase and
is changing but you can give it a try. See documentation at
http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/remote-debugging.html
In particular you should be interested in the console notifications: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/protocol/console.html#events

Answer (score 1):

While fully accepting that the remote-shell-port is deprecated, I found that starting two instances of chrome - one without the remote-shell-port and one with - and then working with the first instance works. Note that I found that the ordering was important, start the instance with the remote-shell-port second ...

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\rlong\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
"C:\Documents and Settings\rlong\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-shell-port=9222
```